# Trying to work on responsiveness of login form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the page responsive and facing some issues I don't know what I did wrong. its just basic and I am not able to do it. Please check the plnkr link and let me know what I did wrong

[Here's the plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/kpeXWLhnKRIsAk3RCiRZ?p=preview)

```
    .login-btn, .btn.login-btn {
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  min-width: 140px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.login-cont input[type="text"], .login-cont input[type="password"]  {
  border: 1px solid #61839C;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 358px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;

  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;


}
```

Comment: Your question is far too vague to be answerable in its current form.

Comment: The login form which i created is not responsive

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive"?

Comment: it should work on all devices

Comment: You did no use what bootstrap offers, try their form given by bootstrap.
Check out the form [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any bootstrap css or js links. And you need to give width: 100% to the input tag.
Check out this example.
It is responsive

```js
.login-btn, .btn.login-btn {
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  min-width: 140px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.login-cont input[type="text"], .login-cont input[type="password"]  {
  border: 1px solid #61839C;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="centering text-center">
      <div class="login-cont col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 vcenter">
        <form id="login_form" name="login-form" #f="ngForm"  role="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" novalidate>
          <label id="loginError" class="login-error"></label>

            <img src="https://www.islonline.com/static/v7/images/logo-islonline.svg"   class="img-responsive" alt="logo" width="334" height="100">

    
            <input id="username" class="form-control"  type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" required>
            <!--div *ngIf="f.submitted && username.invalid">Username is required</div-->
          <input id="userPassword" class="form-control"  type="password" name="userPassword" required placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password">
          <div class="forgot-password-form">
            <span>Forgot Password ?</span>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn login-btn">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```